# NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

I try to learn Angular with documentation but I have an error but this code work (I learn with this tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4):

> NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

I found this I should import commonModule in app.module.ts. But it doesn't work. Why? Do, you think that learning with offical documentation is good idea?

Comment: That's the tutorial, but can you please provide the code you wrote that is throwing the error.

Comment: replace `ngif` with `ngIf`.

Answer (score 2):

> Common module is common for all modules.
> if you are using lazy loaded modules then it must contains the CommonModule as well

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use the format like this :

```
    <div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">
    Content to render when condition is true.
    </div> 
    <ng-template #elseBlock>Content to render when condition is false.
    </ng-template>
```